# Is superuser growing at a much faster rate than serverfault?

Tags: discussion, subjective

Looks like Serverfault is going to take a long time to hit even a paltry 10000 questions although the quality has been superb.  Superuser is less than a week old and has over 1000 questions.

In one year, what do you think the number of questions on SuperUser and ServerFault will be and why?

Comment: well, a year later the number of questions are about the same, right around 55K each

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about two specific sites on the network not related to Stack Overflow or the network as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clever sysadmins are probably too busy to dilly dally on forums, cleaning up after code monkeys rep whoring on stackoverflow. Code monkey are, of course, all super users.

Seriously, I find serverfault a lot harder to follow then meta or SO. A combination of exotic technical stuff and less clear tags.

Relating to my main skills, SQL Server, I usually find [Paul Randall](https://serverfault.com/users/1992/paul-randal) has cleaned up already. Who am I to answer a log or DBCC question after Him?

Comment: Wow, that Paul Randall looks like quite an impressive character.

Answer (score 11):

I think SuperUser is going to definitely surpass ServerFault in terms of page views, questions, and overall activity. This is directly because of the subject matters. ServerFault has a lot of highly technical subject matter that will only work for people with a lot of SysAdmin type experience. SuperUser questions are going to be a lot easier for your typical computer power users to be able to answer.

Comment: Will you count also the close ones? I am expecting that after the first two weeks the ratio of closed questions will be much higher than SU and SO

Comment: The amount of stuff that gets on SO will be much higher and the ratio will remain that way because it has a more narrow focus, so things will undoubtedly get closed a lot more often. SU will have a lot broader range of accepted types of questions, which means fewer closings. Now things that get moved to community wiki, that is a COMPLETELY different matter.

Answer (score 3):

I'll second TheTXI's answer.

I asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/39110/why-cant-the-iis-installer-cant-copy-staxmem-dll-despite-it-being-in-the-folder) on Server Fault and got one (not particularly helpful) answer a day later and then nothing.

I asked [the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/240/why-cant-the-iis-installer-cant-copy-staxmem-dll-despite-it-being-in-the-folder) on Super User and got an answer the same day.

Admittedly it's not particularly scientific, but it does illustrate TheTXI's point about the audience for each site.

Comment: Wow, that's not probably what the guys who made the site would want to see, I'd think an IIS question does belong on ServerFault.

Comment: So do I which is why I asked it on ServerFault first! It was my own PC that was causing the problem, so I can see why SuperUser might be seen as more appropriate.

Comment: Even though SU is not public yet, cool

Comment: installing IIS on Windows XP does not equal sysadmin work.. that's either a developer or superuser question.

Comment: @Jeff - SuperUser wasn't open when I had the initial problem, so I thought I'd ask the question on ServerFault anyway just in case.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect? One website is for a rather specific niche that can sometimes easily fall under SO's umbrella (or now, SuperUser's), while the other is a free-for-all melee where anything related to a computer goes. It's only natural that SuperUser is more popular, I wouldn't be surprised if it ends up being the most popular of the trilogy, to be honest.

Comment: I'd think I'd be more apt to have a real question about a topic relevant on ServerFault, than on SuperUser (especially if I wanted a real answer) and I'm a programmer, not a sysadmin.  I kind of think ServerFault will have lasting usefulness whereas SuperUser may be a flash in the pan sort of experience

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser is amazing than any others in the SO Quadrilogy. It is growing faster than others definitely.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that ServerFault is also suffering a little from its' own image. There may very well be people that can answer SF questions, but do not even go there because they perceive themselves as not being 'expert' enough to belong on a SysAdmin site.

Pure speculation of course, but I wouldn't be surprised.